# Prove: if $B$ is semidefinite, then $B_{11}$ is semidefinite as well

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite, block-matrices

If
$$B = \begin{bmatrix} B_{11} & B_{12} \\ B_{21} & B_{22} \end{bmatrix}$$
is a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix of order $p$, prove that its leading principal submatrix $B_{11}$ of order $q$ is also positive semidefinite.

Comment: $B_{11}$ at least semidefinite it can be positively defined as well.Since $x^T B x\ge 0$ for all $x$ by definition of $B$ it will be also and for $=(y,0)$ where $y$ is arbitrary $q$-vector. But then $x^T B x=y^TB_{11} y \ge 0$.

Comment: Hey Alex. I'm still a bit confused on the y part and such. Can you elaborate?

Comment: $x^TBx=y^TB_{11}y+y^TB_{12}0+0^TB_{21}x +0^TB_{22}=y^TB_{11}y$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $B$ is positive (negative) semidefinite iff $x^TBx \geq 0$ ($x^TBx \leq 0$) for every vector $x$.

Now, let $x$ be the "block vector" $x = \pmatrix{y\\0}$.  We note that
$$
x^TBx = \pmatrix{y^T&0} \pmatrix{B_{11}&B_{12}\\B_{21}&B_{22}} \pmatrix{y\\0} =
y^T B_{11} y
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $B_{11}$ is a symmetric submatrix of a symmetric matrix $B$ and apply [Cauchy interlacing theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem).